# why disable one local interrupt or preemption can cause the whole system with 4 cpus unresponsive

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I did some experiments and found that whenever I close the local interrupt in a kernel module, the system would immediately hang, even does not response the keyboard interrupt.(The system has 4 CPUs and the OS is ubuntu 11.10) Close the local interrupt should just make one CPU disabled (I guess), but I still have 3 free CPUs.(confused).

Similar with local interrupt disabled, when I disable preemption (preempt_disable)in a kernel module, the system also does not response to me anymore. when I change the code in one kernel module with codes that

```
for(;;) 
{
    preempt_disable(); 
    /* ---did some thing fast here--- */ 
    preempt_enable()
}
```

the system responses to me at the beginning, but when I open another console or do something else subsequently, the system hangs totally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that the kernel wants to execute an operation on all CPU's, such as an RCU synchronize, or cache-related synchronization or whatever. Then you're hosed.

SMP is not a license to carelessly hog a processor to yourself.

That kind of thing can be arranged. I mean you could have a CPU that is not online as far as the kernel is concerned, and which you use to run whatever you want.

Comment: Does anyone outside of Canada not know what "hosed" means?

Comment: Hi Kaz,thx for your reply. I do not understand the detailed mechanism about operations on all CPUs. As you explained, if some operation about synchronization among all CPUs occur, and unfortunately in the same time, one CPU interrupt disabled, the whole system would halt/hang? I am still confused about it since that would be a probable event and the SMP should have handled it, at least CPU should throw one exception about that scenario.

Comment: The operation "call function (*f)() on every processor" cannot work if interrupts are disabled on some of the processors, because it requires interrupts.

Comment: I know what you mean, but if one CPU's interrupt is disabled, the routine which calls the "call function (*f)() on every processor" operation or the operation itself should notice that and do something, i.e, wait the interrupt enable again or just throw an fatal exception if the operation is critical, at least not hanging the whole system there.

Comment: @Roger: It waits until the operation completes on all processors - which means it waits until interrupts get enabled on the processor in question.  If interrupts *never* get enabled, it'll wait forever.  This isn't a bug, because interrupts are not supposed to be disabled for long periods.

Comment: @caf:Thx. I got it about the interrupt disabled argument. Can you give me a scenario about why preemption disabled also causes this failure?