# What consequences are there to disabling interrupts/preemption for a long period?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

In the Linux kernel, there are a lot of functions, for example on_each_cpu_mask, that have documentation warning against passing in callbacks that run for long periods of time because interrupts and/or preemption will be disabled for the duration of the callback. It's unclear though if the callback "must" be short because it being long will just cause terrible system performance, or because a long running callback will actually break the correctness of the system somehow.

Obviously while interrupts and preemption are disabled the busy core can't do any other work, and you can concoct situations where you could force deadlock by having two CPUs waiting for one another. But for the sake of argument say the callback just does a bunch of pure computation that takes a significant amount of time and then returns. Can this somehow break the kernel? If so how long is too long? Or does performance just suffer until the computation is done?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling interrupts on one CPU for any period of time will eventually result in all other CPUs hanging, as the kernel frequently needs to perform short operations on all CPUs. Leaving interrupts off on any CPU will prevent it from completing these operations. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919137/149341))

Disabling interrupts on *all* CPUs, either intentionally or unintentionally, will make the system *completely* unresponsive. This includes the user interface (including TTY switching at the console), as well as tasks which the kernel normally performs automatically, like responding to network activity (like ARP responses and TCP acknowledgements) or performing thermal management tasks (like adjusting system fan speeds). This is bad. Don't do it.